# Where do experimental design questions belong?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have experimental design questions such as "how can I test whether allowing cash payments increase sales while the products sold cannot be predetermined (i.e. how to remove bias from product)?" Which site is more appropriate:

- OnStartups
- Statistical Analysis

Or is this topic outside the scope of Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a regular on stats.SE but a total newbie here on meta.SE, and I'd never visited answers.onstartups.com until just now.

Experimental design questions would be most welcome on stats.SE. Statisticians often complain that their advice is sought only when it's too late—see [the quote currently in 3rd place](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/726/famous-statistician-quotes/739#739) in our list of favorite statistician quotes.

Two caveats though:

1. Be prepared to spend a while explaining your question and its setting. Statisticians often need to know more background than their clients expect, and few statisticians have experience in business startups. (I admit I don't understand your example at present.)
2. If you follow statistical advice at the design stage, you'll probably need it at the analysis stage too.

Comment: Thanks! I have posted my question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4337/what-to-do-with-confounding-variables)

Comment: Nice question, I've upvoted it. I don't have time to respond immediately, but I expect others will soon.